# derived class with templated parent class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, derived-class

I have parent class

```
template <class T_ENUM>
class A
{
public:
  A(int*);
  ~A();
}
```

now when i create a derived class, is it allowed to initialize the template on parent class ?

```
enum Benum {e1, e2, e3};

class B : public A<Benum >
{
public:
  B(int* a):A(a);
  ~B();
}
```

I get following compile error as

> undefined reference to `B::B(int*)'

in another file where i include the class defenition header file.

Comment: i see when i initialize, i get undefined reference to `B::B(int*)'

Comment: You should have `B(int* a) : A<Benum>(a) {}` (you probably should also make these single argument constructors `explicit`).

Comment: could you elaborate " (you probably should also make these single argument constructors explicit)"

Comment: Add the keyword "explicit" to the constructor.  It prevents you from accidentally casting an int* into a B.

Comment: The error/problem has nothing to do with *derived class with templated parent class*, but was due to a simple syntax bug. Hence, I propose to close this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> B(int* a):A(a);

This should produce a compilation error.

Instead the constructor should be implemented as:

```
B(int* a) : A(a) {}
```

---

Edit:

You probably also want to make your single argument constructors `explicit`. For example:

```
class B
{
public:
    explicit B(int* a);
};
```

This prevents implicit type conversion from `int*` to `B`.

---

**MCVE Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

enum Benum
{
    e1,
    e2,
    e3
};

template<class T_ENUM>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int*)
    {
        std::cout << "A ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~A()
    {
    }
};

class B : public A<Benum>
{
public:
    explicit B(int* a) : A(a)
    {
        std::cout << "B ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~B()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x = 3;

    B b(&x);

    return 0;
}
```

**MCVE Output:**

```
A ctor
B ctor
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5f1df7fd40cbd9b)

Comment: It is fine to just use `A(a)` in this case. Because `A<Benum>` is not dependent, the *injected-class-name* `A::A` will be found during unqualified lookup in the scope of `B`.

Comment: @bicepjai Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want help with your error.